# Is it better to give a solution to the question or to change the context?

Tags: discussion

It seems to be opinion that question quality is lowering on SO. Personally it seems the same to me. With that comes a raft of questions asked by people looking for a copy-paste solution to the exact question they have - to put it simply, they want personal debugging.

However, many of these questions can be improved. Instead of telling John Bloggs that this is his solution, I could instead suggest that he instead use a different framework which could deal with his problem more easily. This mayrequire additional setup, but along the way Mr. Bloggs will acquire some new programming knowledge.

The problem with changing the OP's question context like this is that it often generates downvotes and annoyed comments from high-rep users wondering why you did it.

So the question is: is it better to debug and send John Bloggs on his way, or to actually teach him something he could go on to use? Is there a way of doing both? How should questions like this be answered?

Comment: If you reinterpret his question instead of answering literally and/or making him reformulate his question, you must tread a very fine line and provide exceptional content to avoid getting voted to oblivion. Even is you do, there are no guarantees. Anyway, the proper course is probably not answering the question (as the question is *not useful* and answering it as-is is thus likely not useful for the site), nor just reinterpreting (as your answer than *does not answer the question and thus is not useful*). First order of business (and probably the hardest) is making him (want to) learn at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always best to make sure that your answer can be applicable for someone with the same or similar question. I always try to show a new way to solve their problem if it is better than what they are doing.

Simply debugging their code does not always make your answer applicable to someone with a similar problem. However, showing them a better way to do what they want does make it applicable and therefore better to do.

As for high-rep users getting annoyed when you change the context, it is important that your recontexting (this should be a word ...) of the question works really well and everyone understands that it is something you recommend. Sometimes, you can even guide them on how to use what you suggest. You can also debug their code and then give the suggestion, since no one can really complain about that.

Basically, if you recontext the question, make sure you explain why it is better, state it as a suggestion, and guide them along.

There are times when it is better not to recontext it. Some reasons why you might not want to is if you can't come up with a reason why your suggestion is better than what they have, they might not have access to the resources that your suggestion will require, or it is really easy to debug.

It is really up to you to decide if you should recontext it, but keep in mind what I have said. Teaching the guy who asks the question is OK, but it is necessary to make all your answers applicable to someone with a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

I think an example question would be mighty helpful here. However, if they ask for a copy/paste solution then the question is mostly likely too broad and should be closed as such and possibly downvoted...don't answer.

If it is a legitimate question and suitable for the site then you should answer according to what the user is asking for (assuming you can provide such an answer). Then, if you have a better way, IYHO, then it is perfectly fine to suggest such a way. This will make it **very** useful for others that may be trying the same "wrong" way.

If you don't want to provide an answer for what the user is asking but you would like to suggest a different approach then this may be more suitable as a comment (assuming it will fit as a comment).